# How to load view in zend 1?

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework, angular-ui-router

I am new to zend and integrating angular in zend. Using zend 1. I want to write action in my controller that will load/return given view. So I can use that action in temaplateUrl in my app.js for loading template for state.

```
public function templateAction() {
   //here i will pass one parameter <name>
   //so this action should return <name>.phtml
   //so i can use it as template in my loaded state.
}
```

I want something like this, as we can do in Code Igniter,

```
public function template() {
   $this->load->view('name');
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure but it seems you are looking to render phtml(view) from controller action.

```
$this->render('script.phtml');
```

The render() function will render the given view script within the variable scope of the script is was called from.

```
$this->partial('script.phtml', array('var1' => 'value 1', 'var2' => 'value 2'));
```

partial() will also render the given view script, but you can define a special variable scope: you can pass all requested parameters in an array.

```
public function templateAction() {
    //your other code goes here

   $this->partial('script.phtml', array('var1' => 'value 1', 'var2' => 'value 2'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richie...render() worked for me...I wanted to return view only..so just needed to disable layout first and use render()...Thanks for giving explanation about partial() as well...I had not know about partial()....

Answer (score 0):

you can do for example

```
$this->view->retour="test";
```